# CPLEX OPL error in set declaration

Tags: declaration, cplex, opl

I'm implementing a two-phase method in CPLEX OPL.

I would like to create a set containing the unitary values of a variable obtained during my initial phase. In order to initialize my second phase, I make a getValue(X) to recover the optimal values for that boolean variable indexed in i,j,k. Later, inside a double loop on indices "j" and "k" I try to declare the set "S" of the unitary values of "X" along the i-dimension.

However, I fail to make a proper set declaration... I've already tried using:

```
var S = {i | i in I : X[i][j][k] == 1};
int S = {i | i in I : X[i][j][k] == 1};
{int} S = {i | i in I : X[i][j][k] == 1};
```

But I always get the error: "Illegal use of a reserved keyword". I know that my set declaration isn't good but have no idea of how to declare it in order to have my set S containing the values of I for which X[i][j][k] == 1.

Could you please provide some help?
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> range I=1..2;
>   range J=1..2;
>   range K=1..2;
>   int X[i in I][j in J][k in K]=(i==1)&&(j==1)&&(k==1)?1:0;
>
> int v[i in I]=1<=sum(j in J,k in K )(X[i][j][k] == 1);
>   {int} S = {i | i in I : v[i] == 1};
>
> execute
>   {
>   writeln(S);
>   }

could help

regards

Comment: Thanks for your help @AlexFleischer ! I'm a newbie in CPLEX OPL, could you please help me understand the code? First you initialize the ranges I, J and K (why only for two elements? I have a bit more, say nI, nJ and nK). Later you define X as a binary taking the unitary value whenever i=j=k=1, zero otherwise. Right? But the X values are given to me as the optimal values of the 1st phase model. How could I extend your proposition to nI, nJ and nK elements per dimension?